# order by is causing select query to return null values

Tags: mysql, sql

the mysql query below works perfectly if i do not use the **ORDER BY CLAUSE** .

However, once i insert an **order by** within the select to return values by **pictureRating** (i.e users with the highest quality pictures) then the query stops returning all the value. for example it stops returning any values from the tatement table.

```
SELECT u.id,st.message,ph.image
FROM user u  
LEFT OUTER JOIN statement st ON u.id = st.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN photosGallery ph ON u.id = ph.userId
WHERE u.live = 1 
GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY u.pictureRating DESC
```

the tables are :

**user.**

```
 CREATE TABLE users(
id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
pictureRating smallint(6) NULL, 

);
```

**photoGallery**

```
CREATE TABLE photosGallery(
id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
image  VARCHAR(30) NULL
);
```

**statement**

```
CREATE TABLE statement (
id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
message VARCHAR (60) NULL,
);
```

Comment: can you set up a sqlfiddle with some sample data (that reproduce the issue)?

Comment: also: what db are you using? sql or mySql? They don't apply exactly the same syntax

Comment: @LelioFaieta Read the tag description for sql please...

Comment: why `JOIN  statement` you don' use it?

Comment: @fancyPants Oh... I see `,st.message`you are right! thank you

Comment: `WHERE  u.live = 1` there is no `live` column in your `CREATE TABLE users`

Comment: you're doing a branched join, e.g. `<`, instead of a linear `---`, which can/will cause issues if the two joined tables have differing number of records.

Comment: You did post not complete database schema and no sample of data. Post it please.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you use `GROUP BY`. The correct usage is, that every column in the `SELECT` clause either has to appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (if specified, of course), or an aggregate function has to be applied on it. Unfortunately MySQL (and I think it's the only DBMS that does this) allows this, although it can lead to false results. BTW, you can turn this off by setting [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) as [`sql_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html).

Anyway, what's happening is, that the rows in each group are "collapsed" to one row per group. When you don't have an aggregate function like `MIN()` or `MAX()` applied on it, a random row of the group is displayed. In your case this are the rows with the `NULL` values.

Comment: hey FancyPants nice to see you again. i am not entirely sure i understand what you said. Also, i am not clear what the solution should be. do you mean that i should take out the group by clause ( i did try taking it out and the results were even more inaccurate)

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to do. What should the query return?

Comment: hey. all the values from the table. i am doing a sample on the mysqlFiddle.