# How to optimize a query in mysql while using "group by" clause?

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query which is taking about 52 seconds if grouped by 'supervisor' otherwise it completes within 2 or 3 seconds:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS MONTHNAME(o.sale_on) AS DATE,
       SUM(od.current_status_id=1) AS sales,
       IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN od.current_status_id=2
                  OR od.current_status_id=3 THEN
                   (SELECT SUM(amount)
                    FROM order_refund_chargeback
                    WHERE order_detail_id = od.order_detail_id) END),0) AS total_outflow,
       IFNULL(
               (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user_first_name," ",user_last_name))
                FROM user_detail
                WHERE user_id IN
                  (SELECT manager_id
                   FROM `user_org_map`
                   WHERE user_id = o.assigned_to)),"") AS supervisor,
       IFNULL(mco.country_name,"") AS country
FROM orders o
RIGHT JOIN order_detail od
    USING (order_id)
LEFT JOIN user_detail ud
    ON ud.user_id = o.assigned_to
LEFT JOIN customer_detail cd
    ON cd.customer_id= o.customer_id
LEFT JOIN master_product mp
    ON mp.product_id = od.product_id
LEFT JOIN master_campaign mc
    ON mc.campaign_id = cd.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN master_country mco
    ON mco.country_id = cd.country
WHERE 1=1
 AND YEAR(o.sale_on) =2015
GROUP BY supervisor
ORDER BY supervisor ASC
LIMIT 0, 12
```

Any suggestion on how to optimize this so that the amount of time can be reduced?

Comment: This query is invalid, have a look at this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33221376/447489

Comment: I did not get that from your explanation how the query is invalid? can you please explain here?

Comment: You group by `supervisor` but select `sale_on`. It doesn't match. Stopped reading your query right there, but your subqueries also seem very odd. Those are dependent subqueries, executed for every row in the result. No wonder your query is slow. Rewrite it with joins, add an `explain select ...` output, show your `create table` statements and so on if you want to optimize it. I actually wonder how you got 5 upvotes on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the date function in the where condition because you could not benefit of potential index help. Instead of the condition `YEAR(o.sale_on) =2015` use condition:

```
o.sale_on BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'.
```

Comment: I replaced, but no luck. Still taking 52+ sec. It works fine if I use -> group by o.sale_on